# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm trying dictionary application but get the error below;

> 01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): Process: taejung.kim.dic, PID: 2439
>           01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
>           ComponentInfo{taejung.kim.dic/taejung.kim.dic.DictionaryMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at taejung.kim.dic.DictionaryMainActivity.onCreate(DictionaryMainActivity.java:45)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>       01-27 06:27:57.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     ... 11 more

The issue may be triggered by OnCreate in main activity, but I can't understand what the problem is.

Below, my scripts;

DictionaryMainActivity.java

```
package taejung.kim.dic;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
`enter code here`
public class DictionaryMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    // Search EditText
    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_main);
        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE", "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800", "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};
        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_list_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" tools:context="taejung.kim.dic.DictionaryMainActivity">
    <!--  모음리스트 -->
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/MoumScroll" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/MoumList" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅏ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅑ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅓ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅕ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅗ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅛ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅜ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅠ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅡ" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="ㅣ" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <!-- 자음리스트 -->
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/JaumScroll" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/JaumList" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/ga" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/na" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/da" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/ra" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/ma" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/ba" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/sa" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/aa" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/ja" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/cha" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/ka" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/ta" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/pa" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/ha" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <!--화면이동  -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/BtLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="8">
        <Button android:id="@+id/BtHelp1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="도움말" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/BtSearch1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="검색" android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Single ListItem -->
    <!-- Product Name -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/product_name" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dip" android:textSize="16dip" android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="taejung.kim.dic" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".DictionaryMainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your `lv` variable. Add

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

after `setContentView()` and before invoking a method on `lv`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` lv is never initialized. So you get an NPE at this line:

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

your `ListView lv;` variable isn't initialized, so you call try to call `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` for not yet created object.